# Swift 3 | CoreData | Custom Entities

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobject

I created a CoreData Model with an Entity "News" :

[image]

I set it to "Manuel/None" and created a NSManagedObject :

```
public class News: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var newsType: Int16
    @NSManaged var newsImageUrl: String
    @NSManaged var newsVideoUrl: String
    @NSManaged var newsTitle: String
    @NSManaged var newsDesc: String

}
```

I want to override the properties of my entity without touching the CoreData Model, just by doing this :

```
extension News {
    @NSManaged var newsUrl: String
}
```

Of course, if I do :

```
news.newsUrl = ""
```

I get a nice

> reason: '-[NSManagedObject setNewsUrl:]: unrecognized selector

How can I add properly new properties in my Entity (without modifying CoreData Model) and, of course, I want this news property to be saved in CoreData ?

TY

Comment: You have to add the property to your entity in the model.

Comment: So there is now way to add a property in a NSManagedObject without modifying CoreData Model ? Even if extensions ? It seems odd !

Comment: The column can not exist in the db if it's not defined in your model.

Comment: Yes ofc I get it but there is no way to add a property to an already exists CoreData Model ? I know there is some class like NSAttributeDescription that could help me to create my custom property but I can't find anything for use it with existing CoreData Model

Comment: You can add a new property like you can for any other class, but not one that is "managed" by Core Data.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I'm a bit disappointed, I hope there was a way since some people doesn't use CoreData Model Editor and create all their entities programmatically.

Comment: It's **very** unusual to create the data model in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you tried doesn't work because it's not enough to just declare the new property, you have to make that property exist in the data model. If you don't edit the model, you have to do the work in your code.

You can modify the entire model in code **until you start using it**. Once you load your persistent store file, you have to treat the object model as read-only. The basic steps would be

1. Ask the `NSManagedObjectModel` for its `entities` or `entitiesByName`.
2. Find the appropriate `NSEntityDescription` in that list.
3. Create a new `NSAttributeDescription` for your new property.
4. Add the new attribute to the `properties` array on the entity.

This is not a good idea, and I strongly recommend not doing it, but it's not impossible. In many years of Core Data coding I've only modified the model in code once, to work around a (since fixed) bug in the model compiler.

Keep in mind that this does not let you avoid doing model migration. Your persistent store file must match the data model that you use. Modifying the model in code will make managing model versions more difficult, and will increase the odds of the app crashing because the models don't match.